# Type 'sudo' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

Tags: command-line, apt, repository

I'm trying to install spotify and after failing every time, I try to do `sudo apt update`,but I am greeted with the message

**E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list**

**E:The list of sources could not be read.**

This was what I entered `curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_5E3C45D7B312C643.gpg | sudo apt-key add -  echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

Answer (score 1):

You have a malformed entry. to remove that:

- ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
  ```
- Remove `sudo` word on line 4
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> To save and exit

or simply run :

```
sed -i 's/sudo//g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Finally you can run Update and Upgrade your system.